# How do you save an inputted email in one component and save it to another?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to store an email a user has inputted to change their password on one modal and then display it on another modal. I have all the code done except this bit. I know I have to use state but am unsure of how to tackle it, especially with storing the value and displaying it on the second modal.
Here is my parent code

```
export default function YourDetails() {
  const [mustLogin, setMustLogin] = useState(true);
  const [isResettingPassword, setIsResettingPassword] = useState(false);
  const [hasResetPassword, setHasResetPassword] = useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const proceedToNextStep = () => navigate('/step4');
  const displayPaymentForm = () => setMustLogin(false);

  const openResetPasswordModal = () => setIsResettingPassword(true);
  const closeResetPasswordModal = () => setIsResettingPassword(false);
  const openResetPasswordConfirmationModal = () => setHasResetPassword(true);
  const closeResetPasswordConfirmationModal = () => setHasResetPassword(false);
  const handleResetPassword = () => {
    // send email to the back end
    // close the modal
    setIsResettingPassword(false);
    // show the confirmation modal
    openResetPasswordConfirmationModal();
  };

  if (mustLogin) {
    return (
      <>
        <ResetYourPasswordModal
          isOpen={isResettingPassword}
          onClose={closeResetPasswordModal}
          onSubmit={handleResetPassword}
        />
        <ResetYourPasswordConfirmationModal
          isOpen={hasResetPassword}
          onClose={closeResetPasswordConfirmationModal}
        />
```

Here is my first modal where a user inputs their email:

```
interface ResetYourPasswordModalInterface {
  isOpen: boolean,
  onClose: () => void,
  onSubmit: (emailOrAccountCode: string) => void,
}

export default function ResetYourPasswordModal(props: ResetYourPasswordModalInterface) {
  const { isOpen, onClose, onSubmit } = props;
  const [emailOrAccountCode, setEmailOrAccountCode] = useState('');

  const handleEmailOrAccountCodeChange = (value:string) => setEmailOrAccountCode(value);
  const handleSubmit = (evt: React.FormEvent) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    onSubmit(emailOrAccountCode);
  };

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} closeModal={onClose}>
      <h1>Reset your password</h1>
      <p>
        Enter the email address you signed up with or your account code,
        and we will email you a link to reset your password.
      </p>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextInput
          name="emailOrAccountCode"
          label="Email or Account Code"
          value={emailOrAccountCode}
          onChange={handleEmailOrAccountCodeChange}
        />
        <Button
          type="submit"
          colour="orange"
          text="RESET PASSWORD"
        />
      </form>
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

And here is the second modal that needs to display their email that was saved in the first modal:

```
interface ResetYourPasswordConfirmationModalInterface {
  isOpen: boolean,
  onClose: () => void,
}

export default function ResetYourPasswordConfirmationModal(
  props: ResetYourPasswordConfirmationModalInterface,
) {
  const { isOpen, onClose } = props;
  const [userEmail] = useState('');

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={isOpen} closeModal={onClose}>
      <h1>Email sent</h1>
      <p>
        {userEmail}
        , we have sent you an email.
      </p>
      <p>Click the reset password button in the email to change your password.</p>
      <Button
        type="button"
        colour="orange"
        text="OK"
        onClick={onClose}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing emailOrAccountCode from ResetYourPasswordModal, but in YourDetails component you can update to below code to get the emailOrAccountCode and store it in a state, so that it can be passed to ResetYourPasswordConfirmationModal

```
  const handleResetPassword = (emailOrAccountCode) => {
    // send email to the back end
    // close the modal
    setIsResettingPassword(false);
    // show the confirmation modal
    // console.log(emailOrAccountCode);
    openResetPasswordConfirmationModal();
  };
```